# Cakephp re-write webroot relative URLs

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, cakephp, routes

I have a cakephp(version 2.6) view file which links to a js file within my webroot.

The issue I'm having is that this js file contains many relative file paths that link to files within the same directory in the webroot folder.

Since the view file is what loads this main js file, cakephp appends the controller name to all of the relative links within this js file.

So /test.js turns into controller-name/test.js

An example of what I need is the following:
When the app is requesting

```
url: mysite.com/codes/commonResources/image.png
```

I need it to request

```
url: mysite.com/commonResources/image.png
```

I've tried some re-write rules within my .htaccess in webroot but nothing seems to be working.

```
RewriteRule ^codes/commonResources/(.*) /commonResources/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Fixing `this js file` so it doesn't do that is a better idea than using mod rewrite.

Comment: I agree, however, the js file is generated with construct 2, a game software and the links are not readable even after de-minification of the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite url using route file go to `app/config/routes.php` set route like as --

```
Router::connect('/mylisting', array('controller' => 'Directory', 'action' => 'mylisting'));
```

in action you will pass view file name and in controller you will pass controller name and  (/mylisting) means which keyword you want to pass in url for this action it`s depend on you you can set whatever you want.